# Errors in Visual Studio 2008 C++

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

In my project in C, I get these errors:

```
error C2371: 'tDatabase' : redefinition; different basic types
db.h(7) : see declaration of 'tDatabase'
error C2223: left of '->numberOfCity' must point to struct/union
error C2198: 'calloc' : too few arguments for call
```

I'm beginner in C. How can I fix it? Thanks.

file: `DB.h`

```
typedef struct Database {
    int numberOfCity;
    tListOfCity* list;
    double **distances;
} tDatabase;

tDatabase *LoadDatabase(char* file);
```

file `DB.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "DB.h"

typedef struct Database{
int numberOfCity;
tListOfCity* list;
double** distances;
} tDatabase;   //this line error C2371

tDatabase* LoadDatabase(char* file) {
FILE* fileName;
tDatabase *input;
char data[100];
int i, j, number = 0;

input = (tDatabase*) calloc(1, sizeof (tDatabase));
input->list = NULL;

fileName = fopen("file.txt", "r");
fscanf(fileName, "%d", &number);     
input->numberOfCity = number;

input->distances = (double**) calloc(data->numberOfCity, sizeof (double*));  //this line Error C2223 and C2198
for (i = 0; i < input->numberOfCity; i++) {
    input->distances[i] = (double*) calloc(input->numberOfCity, sizeof (double));
}

for (i = 0; i <= input->numberOfCity; i++) {
    fgets(data, sizeof (data), fileName);
    input->list = AddOnEnd(input->list, CreateCity(data));
}

for (i = 0; i < input->numberOfCity; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < input->numberOfCity; j++) {
        fscanf(fileName, "%f", &input->distances[i][j]);
    }

fclose(fileName);
return input;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler is telling you not to re-define that structure. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Please tell us what of these error message you don't understand. SO works differently than you seem to assume. Your question title is completely unspecific. How would you think that such a question title would be searchable to be useful for others, later?

Comment: How I should name title, when I had several errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the definition of `struct Database` from your code; this is what the compiler means by "redefinition". You don't need it, because it is already in `"DB.h"`. (That is, in fact what header files are for: To ensure that all c files that use it use the same definition and not a "private" one.)

[Aside: If, on the other hand, you want the struct to be private, i.e. that the fields of the struct can only be accessed from within `"DB.c"`, just put the typedef without the struct body in the header file `"DB.h"`:

```
typedef struct Database tDatabase;
```

Then define the struct with body (but without the `typedef`) in `"DB.c"` as you have done:

```
struct Database {
    int numberOfCity;
    tListOfCity* list;
    double **distances;
};
```

In that case, code from outside `"DB.c"` can include the header, but it can use only pointers to `tDatabase` without getting at the data. All access to this opaque pointer will be done by the methods defined in `"DB.c"`.]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are doing definition the `Database`. So, avoid the problem by removing definition of the `Database` in your DB.c file.

Secondly, `data->numberOfCity,` is wrong, because `data` is declared as char arry, so it doesn't have `numberOfCity` as class member.